# ImageView StartAnimation slows down the UI extremly

Tags: android, animation, user-interface, imageview, rotation

i have a big problem. i try to implement a kind of speedometer. i get the informations like RPM... every 10-100ms from the car over bluetooth. now i want to rotate the rpm needle to the right position. i do this every time i get data.

```
ivNadel.startAnimation(RpmAnim);
ivBoost.startAnimation(BoostAnim);
ivLoad.startAnimation(LoadAnim);
```

the Animations are all implemented like this:

```
//rotate Tachonadel
Rpmcurrentdegree=Rpmcurrentdegree+Rpmdegree;
Rpmdegree=((rpms-lastrpm)*RPMtoDegree);
if(Rpmdegree!=0)
{
    RpmAnim=new RotateAnimation((float)Rpmcurrentdegree, (float)Rpmdegree, ivNadel.getWidth()/2, ivNadel.getHeight()/2);
    RpmAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    RpmAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
    RpmAnim.setFillAfter(true);
}
```

the problem is that the startAnimations slow down the reaction time of the ui by about half a second. when i comment the 3 startAnimation out it works fine again. 
so does anyone know a way how to work around this slow down?

i also tried to start the animation only if there was a change on the degrees but then the ImageView does not hold its new position after the rotateanimation.

plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer your question directly but this link may help

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

It uses a custom UI component drawn and rotates a needle with a canvas rather than animations.

Comment: the problem is that i have to use a given image needle. in this example they use a path

Comment: convert the needle to a bitmap and rotate the bitmap in place of the path.